# When to call `.value` for broadcasts in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is one of the following sub-optimal?

```
    ## First version ##
    def myfunc(val, listparam):
        return val in listparam.value  # .value in function

    mylist_bc = sc.broadcast(mylist)
    rdd.map(lambda val:myfunc(val, mylist_bc))


    ## Second version ##
    def myfunc(val, listparam):
        return val in listparam

    mylist_bc = sc.broadcast(mylist)
    rdd.map(lambda val:myfunc(val, mylist_bc.value))  # .value outside function
```

Is it OK to use the second version for broadcast where they function is unaware of that I'm using a broadcasted value? I thought maybe it would interfere with broadcasting.

Answer (score 1):

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

*After the broadcast variable is created, it should be used instead of the value v in any functions run on the cluster so that v is not shipped to the nodes more than once*

I'd use option #1 - where you know that the executor will use the broadcast variable

Option #2 **might** be problematic , if the value of the broadcast variable will be calculated on the driver, and will be sent as a regular variable to the executors